# Checking if a binary tree is balanced

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-tree, height

I implemented the C++ piece of code below, to check if a binary tree is balanced, i.e. the height of the left and right subtrees differ by at most 1. However, I am not sure if it is efficient, or repeatedly checks subtrees in a bad way. Can someone guide me please?

```
 unordered_map <Node*, int>  height;
    struct Node{
       int key;
       Node* left;
       Node* right;
    }
    bool isBalanced(Node* root){
        if (root == nullptr){
             height[root] = -1;
            return true;
        }
        if (!isBalanced(root->left)) return false;
        if (!isBalanced(root->right)) return false;

        height[root] = max(height[root->left], height[root->right]) + 1;


        return (abs(height[root->left] - height[root->right]) < 1);
}
```

Comment: You can make `isBalanced` to return `int`, -1 for unbalanced or depth otherwise. Then you do not need additional map

Comment: There is a lot of balanced trees, precise what you mean by balanced. Whatever, you should return height and compare heights of left and right subtrees.

Comment: @DieterLücking Confusing. What do you mean?

Comment: @DieterLücking You mean there is a bug?

Comment: @user25004 If you are sure that your code is **actually working** and you're asking for improvement, ask at [SE Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) please, providing the complete code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks a lot! I had not heard about that site.

Comment: What type of balancing algorithm are you wanting to focus on or implement? [AVL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree), [Red-Black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), [Splay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree), [Scapegoat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scapegoat_tree)?

Comment: @callyalater None. Just want to verify balancing and the definition is in the problem statement.

Answer (score 3):

I will try to pass the idea using pseudo-code.

```
int CheckTreeHeight(Node root)
{
  if(root == null) return 0; // Height of 0.

  // Check if left is balanaced
  int leftChildHeight = CheckTreeHeight(root.left);
  if(leftChildHeight == -1) return -1; // Not Balanced

  // Check if right is balanaced
  int rightChildHeight = CheckTreeHeight(root.right);
  if(rightChildHeight == -1) return -1; // Not Balanced

  // Check if current node is balanced
  int heightDifference = leftChildHeight - rightChildHeight;

  if(Math.abs(heightDifference) > 1)
   return -1; // not balanaced
  else
   return Math.max(leftChildHeight, rightChildHeight) + 1; // Return Height
}

bool IsBalanced(Node root)
{
   if(CheckTreeHeight(root) == -1)
   {
      return false;
   }
   else
   {
      return true;
   }
}
```

This algorithm performs in `O(n)` time complexity and `O(H)` space complexity, where `h` is the height of the tree.

As mentioned by the algorithm's author, the idea is that we inspect the children of the root (that is `left` and `right`) recursively until we found unbalanced one, where we return `-1`.

With this technique, we return immediately if any of the sub-trees are unbalanced.

More information about this implementation you can find in the book mentioned in the reference bellow.

**Reference**
[Cracking the Coding Interview 6th Edition](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Cracking-Coding-Interview-6th-Edition/dp/0984782850/ref=dp_ob_title_bk)

Comment: `if( condition ) return false; else return true;` looks ugly, `return !condition;` should be used instead